# dijit.Tree refresh and focusNode

Tags: tree, dojo

I found out how to refresh a tree and everything works fine. But now I want to focus on a specific node and it always says that the _itemNodesMap is undefined.

Here is what I have:

```
    require([
     "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
     "dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel", "dijit/Tree",
     "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(win, Ifrs, ForestStoreModel, Tree){
    dojo.extend(Tree, {

      reload: function (data, path) {               
     this.dndController.selectNone();
 this.model.store.clearOnClose = true;
 this.model.store.close(); 
 this._itemNodesMap = {};
 this.rootNode.state = "UNCHECKED";
 this.model.root.children = null;
 this.rootNode.destroyRecursive();

     var _data  = {identifier: "id", label: "label", items: data};
 var _store = new Ifrs({data:_data});
 var _treeModel = new ForestStoreModel({
        store: _store,
            rootId:"root",
            rootLabel:"Things",
            childrenAttr:["children"]
  });
    this.model.constructor(_treeModel);
    this.postMixInProperties();
    this._load();
    path.unshift("root");
    this.set('path',path);
    }});
```

for focussing I tried to add the following and call it after setting the path:

```
   scroll : function(path){
   var itemnode = this._itemNodesMap[path[path.length-1]];
   this.focusNode(itemnode[0]);
   }
```

But I always get that _itemNodesMap is undefined. Why? Tree is displayed, path is set and everything except this works. Would be great to get some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that setting the path is a deferred process, so assuming the `path` variable in your `scroll` function has taken that into consideration, I would use the following to focus on your tree item (node) in your `then` function:

```
var item = myTree.path[path.length-1];
var nodes = myTree.getNodesByItem(item);
if (nodes && nodes.length > 0 && nodes[0]) {
    nodes[0].domNode.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't use any deferred and just set the path with this.set('path',path);

Comment: Using your code now results in the same problem. myTree.path (or in my case it it is this.path[path.lenght-1]) is undefined. Even though the path in the view is set correctly afterwards. Should I try to use deferred? (Never did so before, so I'm a little inexperienced)

Comment: function call is:  dijit.byId("myTree").reload(data, path); dijit.byId("myTree").scroll(path);

Comment: What is in your path?  I'm assuming that you already know which item you want to scroll to and have constructed the path to that item.  If so, the above code should work (because it works for my application).  As far as setting the path using a deferred, see this bug report: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11304

Comment: Yeah in my path is the id. But unfortunately your code doesn't work either even though I have the id. In "nodes" it tells me that it is undefined. But I can convince that the item is in the tree, after the tree is fully build (it is correctly selected, when setting the path!). When I click a second time now without reloading and just focusing, everything works fine (_itemNodesMap is filled correctly too). My guess is, that the tree is not fully build when the code is run. Can I force him to wait?

Comment: You can try to put the call to your focus function in the `onLoad` function of your tree.  Dojo's `onLoad` comment says:

`onLoad: function(){
  // summary:
  //    Called when tree finishes loading and expanding.
  // description:
  //    If persist == true the loading may encompass many levels of fetches
  //    from the data store, each asynchronous.   Waits for all to finish.
  // tags:
  //    callback
},`  Sorry for the poor formatting.  It's a function that is meant to be overloaded and does nothing itself.  There are only comments to tell how it works.

Comment: I tried this. But the onload is just called the very first time I load the page and then never again. Afterwards I just call my own reload function, which is not forcing the onload to be called again. Mmh... there must be a solution, I'm sure there is

Comment: I still feel like `Deferred` is the way to go.  You may need to turn your `reload` function into a deferred before setting your path.  And `then` use a different deferred to set your path.  And `then` focus on your node.  Also, you're passing in the path as a parameter to `reload`.  I wonder if that path is no longer valid because by the time you use it, you've destroyed the contents of the tree.  Perhaps you should pass the id of the item you want to scroll to and build your path *after* you've reloaded.  Sorry, I think that's the last of my ideas :(

Comment: Ok, I'll try the deferred! 
Setting the path is working for some reason. (Even though I'm still wondering why, because as you said the tree content seems to be destroyed... but I have no error there, the path is always selected and the correct "leaves" are opened) Just focussing doesn't work. Because I need the node to focus and can't just do it with the id.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is that _itemNodesMap is undefined, its not a problem with _itemNodesMap, but rather that your 'this' is not what you think it is at the point of wherever the scroll function is being called (likely through an event, which is likely using the global object for 'this').

You should try using "dojo/_base/lang" and the lang.hitch function to ensure your 'this' will always be original object.

```
require([
    ...
    "dojo/_base/lang"
], function(..., lang){
...
    scroll: lang.hitch(this, function(path){
        var itemnode = this._itemNodesMap[path[path.length-1]];
        this.focusNode(itemnode[0]);
    })
....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after adding your code, this is not the Treeobject anymore, but the window, which has no _itemNodesMap again.